# Video is not playing using MPMoviePlayerContrller

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

how to play a video in iPhone sdk using MPMoviePlayerViewController,here i capture video through device and save that particular video in documents directory .
please tell me any one....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get Document Directory Path:

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
```

Then you can use any of the directory listing APIs of NSFileManager.

```
NSError * error;
NSArray * directoryContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error];
```

Now You have all contents at Directory Path (all videos stored) in array

```
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL UrlWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsDirectory,[directoryContents objectAtIndex:0]]]; //check which url u want play as video name is in nsarray i have selected one random video name.
```

Use MovieControllerPlayer instance to play url:

```
 MPMoviePlayerViewController *mpViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL]; 
 [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mpViewController]; 
 [mpViewController.view setCenter:yourView.center]; 
 //[mpViewController release];
```

Hope useful.

Comment: ok i already do this but MPMoviePlayerViewController presenting the moviePlayer View and then dismissing without playing the video.....

Comment: Use this: MPMoviePlayerViewController *mpViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];

[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mpViewController];

[mpViewController.view setCenter:yourView.center];
[mpViewController release];

Comment: how can i play in another view not in present view?

Comment: [YourView addSubView:MoviePlayerControllerInstance.view];

Comment: Same problem when i use your code the player view presenting and then dismissing with out playing my video.

Comment: in which ios r u playing? and is your video 3gp.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12140/discussion-between-safecase-and-krishna-rambathri)